# Windows Phone 8.1 Action Center like page design

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to move an object in a page form top to down on user finger movement using translate transform. we should see page contents as the bar goes down the page and sits at bottom.

Just like Action Center in windows phone 8.1.

Please let me know any ideas how we can design. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question!

My first thought was to do something like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff426933(v=vs.95).aspx).
You could get the touch input location and then move a rectangle from the top of the screen and translate it down according to they Y Cord of the Touch Input.

**EDIT:**
Okay so here is what you can do.

Create a Canvas and position it somewhere at the top ( i gave it the height of 14 in collapsed state).

Then create a `private void cn_ManipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)` event and make it set the height of the Canvas. I also included a `float i` to later make it snap back or cover the entire screen if the user lets go during the pull-event.

```
private void cn_ManipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            cn.Height += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
            i = (float)e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation.Y;

        }
```

And thats it. You can also add this event to make it snap back or go cover the full screen when the user lets go.

```
private void cn_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(i < 100)
            {
                cn.Height = 14; 
            }
            else
            {
                cn.Height = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;  
            }
        }
```

Of course you can add smoother animations so it slowly goes back into the collapsed view or fills the entire page.
I hope this helps!

Comment: i've tried using these events, Problem is that complete Rectangle will move along Y, i need still page with a bottom bar which moves along Y. Just Like Action Center bar.

Comment: Try changing the height of the rectangle instead of its Y-location.

Comment: Thanks,but I couldn't get the expected result. How about having a grid view to show content and moving a grid view footer. Initially it should only show footer and as the user holds and moves down the footer it should show the content of grid view. Is it possible. I hope my i have conveyed the question to you properly.

Comment: Consider using a Canvas instead of a Grid view, to get the "Revealing" effect like with the Action Center. Simply change the height of the Canvas, which holds all your Buttons, TextViews etc.

Comment: Thanks :). worked with some minor edit's in code to support for phone properties.